# How to reduce condition checks with the same action?

Tags: java

The following code snippet checks for condition, then all in the 3 cases it does the same thing:

```
if (TEMP_UUID_1.equals(fsTempUUID) && "P1".equals(siv.getParentUuid())) {
       iRating.setFinSalesAmount(value);
} else if (TEMP_UUID_2.equals(fsTempUUID) && "P2".equals(siv.getParentUuid())) {
       iRating.setFinSalesAmount(value);
} else if (TEMP_UUID_3.equals(fsTempUUID) && "P3".equals(siv.getParentUuid())) {
       iRating.setFinSalesAmount(value);
}
```

Can I transform this somehow, since after checking the condition, it does the same thing?

Comment: why don't you use `||`  ?

Comment: use "or" (`||`)?

Comment: What is TEMP_UUID_1? If it is a string you could use a switch statement.

Comment: Not sure if you can, but you could if you want to. You see this not a free homework service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single `if` statement and separate these conditions with a `OR` operator (`||`):

```
if ( TEMP_UUID_1.equals(fsTempUUID) && "P1".equals(siv.getParentUuid() 
     || 
    TEMP_UUID_2.equals(fsTempUUID) && "P2".equals(siv.getParentUuid()
    ||
    TEMP_UUID_3.equals(fsTempUUID) && "P3".equals(siv.getParentUuid() ){

    iRating.setFinSalesAmount(value);
}
```

You don't need to surround the initial conditions with parenthesis as `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.